# Rails 3: Duplicate validation error messages during testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, machinist

I'm getting some weird validation behavior: it's duplicating my validation error messages and I can't figure out what's causing it... it doesn't do this in the rails console.

Here is the validation from my Phone model:

```
# phone.rb
validates :number, :length => { :minimum => 3 }
```

My spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Phone do
  it "requires a number" do
    user = User.make!
    @p = Phone.new(number:nil,user_id:user.id,type:2)
    @p.valid?
    puts @p.errors.inspect 
    @p.should have(1).error_on(:number)
  end
```

My test results:

```
# rspec and machinist
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000036f1258 @base=#<Phone id: nil, user_id: 614, kind: nil, number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:number=>["is too short (minimum is 3 characters)", "is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"]}>
F

Failures:

  1) Phone requires a number
     Failure/Error: @p.should have(1).error_on(:number)
       expected 1 error on :number, got 2
     # ./spec/models/phone_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.50988 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

As you can see, I'm getting "is too short (minimum is 3 characters)" twice... It's also /only/ happening during testing.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what do your association definitions look like and do you use validates_associated?

Comment: In Phone, it `has_one :user`, and in User, it `has_many :phones`.  I started using `valid_attribute` gem to test my validatons, and that is much nicer than this method.

Comment: nope... not yet.  Hasn't been an issue since I stopped testing that way.

Comment: Stab in the dark -- what if you change `describe Phone do` to `describe 'Phone' do` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
```

in the spec_helper.rb file, in the Spork.each_run block

If you change the method 'load' to 'require', it fixes the problem.

Or if you have a recent enough version of Spork, you can remove the line altogether.
I am pretty sure the error is caused when someone is installing a newer version Spork(0.9.0+) with old instructions, because the line:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
```

doesn't even has to be stated explicitly in the spec_helper.rb file anymore.  If it is then when the load method is used in the spec_helper.rb file, it reloads the files specified , most likely the cause of the strange RSpec duplicate validations errors.

Comment: A lot of people voted for this one, I'm going to mark it as answered (I haven't used spork in a long time).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue of duplicate error messages, but it seemed to stem from my use of a different directory structure than the standard, e.g.:

```
- app
  \- models_one
  |- models_two
  |- models_three
```

My `load`/`require` call in the `Spork.each_run` block looked like this:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models_*/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
```

I removed this and replaced it with these:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
```

And there were no more duplicate error messages.

I was helped by this post: http://adams.co.tt/blog/2012/04/12/duplicate-active-model-validation-errors/ in which the author says it's a 1.8.7-specific problem which involves requiring different paths which resolve to the same file, but I am using 1.9.3 so it may not be related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to solve your problem, but rspec is very quirky if you don't follow rspec convention. Try some more idiomatic rspec like the following:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Phone do
  context :validations do
    let(:user) { double(:user) }
    subject { Phone.new(number:nil,user_id:user.id,type:2) }

    before do
      subject.valid?
    end

    it 'should have a minimum length of 3' do
      subject.should have(1).error_on(:number)
    end
  end
end
```

I'd also like to suggest that you shouldn't unit test Rails' built in validations; they are already tested in Rails itself.  Specifically, your length validation is tested in [activemodel/test/cases/validations/length_validation_test.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/test/cases/validations/length_validation_test.rb).  The behavior of the validations should be covered in your integration tests.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this.  The point (for me) for unit testing validations is to _very quickly_ whitelist/blacklist things you care/don't care about (integration tests are not as fast as unit tests!), and the valid_attribute gem works great for this... but, for reference, the above example was taken directly from the rspec website's example on model validation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/model-specs/errors-on

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem (using rspec & spork).

I suspect it's something to do with the model being required twice, causing validations to run twice.

If you explicity `require 'phone'` at the top of your spec, it seems to fix it.

But I'd really like to know what's causing the problem...